# Magento Products disappear due to stock 0 But stock Option not available

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have set Stock management Yes but My website have only three option, i cant put Qty of product. Please help me. My magento version is 1.9.3
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configurable product do not have the `Quantity` field. They are not physical products, so they can't have exact qty amount.

If all associated products of a configurable product are out of stock, then configurable product itself is considered out of stock.

Further more, under `System -> Config -> Catalog -> Inventory`, you can choose if Magento show render out of stock products on the frontend. Maybe this is something that you actually want?

Comment: I want quantity options, basically. so simple product is option that should i use? while theme demo has configurable products and these items are displaying. but suggest me and guide me what should i do.

Comment: Not sure I follow you, but yes, simple products should represent your physical products and you will be able to specify quantity for each one of them. Your products could be missing from the frontend for any number of reasons: 1. Is visibility set to `Catalog` or `Catalog, Search`? 2. Is product status set to `Enabled`? 3. is product assigned to category you are viewing? 4. Is product assigned to a website you are using (if you are using multiple websites)?

Comment: all are set but problem was stock. stock is being display as 0 that is why products are not appearing but i will follow your suggestion and will change all products through mysql query configurable to simple.